# Optimal covering trails for every $k$-dimensional cubic lattice $\mathbb{N}^k := \{(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) : x_i \in \mathbb{N} \wedge n \geq 3\}$

Tags: graph-theory, open-problems, combinatorial-optimization, conjectures, packing-and-covering

After a dozen years spent investigating this particular class of problems, I finally give up and I wish to ask you if any improvement is achievable from here on.

The general problem is as follows:
*Let the $k$-dimensional grid $\mathcal{H}(n,k):=\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\} \times \cdots \times \{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ be given in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^k$. How many line segments connected at their endpoints have the minimum-link covering trails that join all the points of $\mathcal{H}(n,k)$ (i.e., the optimal polygonal chain that visits all the given $n^k$ points by spending the minimum number of line segments)?*

Then, let us call $h(n,k)$ the mentioned minimum number of links.
Accordingly, let us denote with $h_l(n,k)$ the proven lower bound for $h(n,k)$ and with $h_u(n,k)$ the corresponding upper bound so that we can state the following set of relations.

\begin{equation}
h(n,1)=1, \forall n.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
h(n,2)=2 \cdot (n-1), \forall n \geq 3.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
h(1,k)=1, \forall k.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
h(2,k)=3 \cdot 2^{k-2}, \forall k \geq 2.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
h(3,k)=\frac{3^k-1}{2}, \forall k.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
h(n,k) \leq \Bigg(\Bigl\lfloor{\frac{3}{2} \cdot n^2}\Bigl\rfloor - \Bigl\lfloor{\frac{n-1}{4}}\Bigl\rfloor + \Bigl\lfloor{\frac{n+1}{4}}\Bigl\rfloor - \Bigl\lfloor{\frac{n+2}{4}}\Bigl\rfloor + \Bigl\lfloor{\frac{n}{4}}\Bigr\rfloor + n - 1 \Bigg) \cdot n^{k-3} - 1, \forall n\geq 3 \wedge \forall k \geq 3
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
h(n,k) \geq \frac{n^k-1}{n-1}, \forall n \geq 3 \wedge \forall k.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
h(n,k) \leq (h_u(n,3)+1) \cdot n^{k-3}-1, \forall n\geq 3 \wedge \forall k \geq 3.
\end{equation}

Thus, what I have currently found is resumed in the table below, where the strictly proven results are highlighted in the green cells, while the proven bounds are shown in the orange cells.

[[image: Proven bounds for the general <span class=]$\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}\times\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}\times \dots \times\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ points problem in $\mathbb{R}^k$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDGrt.png)

**Conjecture**: $h(n,k)=\frac{n^k-1}{n-1}+c \cdot (n-3)$, where $c = k-1$ iff $h(4,3)=23$, $c = 1$ iff $h(4,3)=22$, or even $c = 0$ iff $h(4,3)=21$ (see also this [Previous discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432645/finding-an-optimal-covering-trail-for-the-set-0-1-2-3-times-0-1-2-3-time) about finding the value of $h(4,3)$).

Any idea to go further (can we see some kind of pattern in the table)?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Trying to get my head around your terminology (link, trail, polygonal chain, turn). Is $n=3$, $k=2$ the old "nine dots puzzle" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_dots_puzzle)?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, you are right. The old nine-dot puzzle is the $n=3 \wedge k=2$ case. A trail is a polygonal chain that can repeat its vertices, but it is not a walk (you cannot go back along the same edge/link), while we can forget the statement about the number of turns... it is redundant here and our goal is just to minimize the length of our covering trail (i.e., the polygonal chain that visits all the $n^k$ points of the given set), and we call this optimal value $h(n,k)$.

Comment: As another ambivalent term, here length = number of "links"

Comment: We can replace "links" with "line segments connected at their endpoints" if it will make the text clearer and more readable. Just let me know and I could easily fix it.