# Locally "unshortable" paths in graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, random-walks, random-graphs, machine-learning

**Setup:** Consider a connected graph G, with diameter "d".

**Informally:** Trivially (by definition of diameter), taking any path $P$  any nodes $P(i)  , P(i+k)$ for $k>d$ can be connected by a SHORTER path.
But what we should expect for nodes $P(i), P(i+k)$ for $k<d$ ? How typically they can be connected by a path shorter than $k$   ?  (depending on d, length(P), G, .. )

**Definition:** Let us say path $P$ is "unshortable" in graph $G$ with diameter $d$, if for any nodes $P(i), P(i+k), k<= d$ the subpath $P(i)-P(i+k)$ is the shortest path between $P(i)$, $P(i+k)$.

Clearly any shortest  path between two nodes $A$,$B$ is unshortable (it is shorter than $d+1$), but there can be longer paths which are still unshortable. On the other had extremely long path - containing almost all nodes in say random graph - typically cannnot unshortable - since you can connect some nearby nodes in a shorter. So estimating length of maximal unshortable path seems to be an interesting question.

**Question 0:** any references discussing such kind of questions ? May be there is another standard name instead of "unshortable" ?

**Question 1:** How long can be the "unshortable" path in given $G,d$ ? Is there any bound  on the length $N$ of the unshortable path in terms of diameter,  something like - for any $G$:  $N < 10d$ or $N < exp(d)$ ? Computing $N$ for given $G$ is NP-hard  ?

**Question 2** Is there any information on the percent of unshortable paths of given length $M$ among all paths in given finite graph $G$ ?  The percent short decrease with $M$ growing. How it might decrease - power-low , exponentially ? In the the words sampling a random path of length $M$ what are the chances for it to be "unshortable" ? Intuitively chances are quite big at least for Cayley graphs $G$ of random permutation groups.

**Relaxing definition:** Let $K<d$ be some positive integer number, let us call path $P$ is $K$-unshortable if any subpath of length $l\le K$ is the shortest path in the graph.

**Question 4:** Same questions above for $K$-unshortable paths.

---

**Motivation:** The context is computational - computing shortest paths for some (very) big graphs. Assume we are interested in the task to find shortest path between nodes $A,B$ in some graph $G$. Moreover, assume we are given a hint: some non-shortest path $P$ between $A,B$ and we want to "shorten" that path.   The  trivial strategy  - just take pairs of nodes $P(i),P(i+u)$ and try to shorten such segments.
Of course, if $u>d$ it is possible - but that can me computationally very hard. It is computationally easy to check subpaths $P(i), P(i+\text{small number})$ .

But the question is - how big are the chances to find such kind of "shortcut" ? Depending on path length, diameter and G ? Any references on that ?

Somewhat related figure by colleague from Kaggle:
https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santa-2023/discussion/470799#2622617 :
[image]

**Computational experiment** not sure I am interpreting the outcomes correctly - but it seems that for some Cayley graphs for Rubik's cube like group, if the paths are $10 * d$ (i.e. 10 times longer than diameter) the paths can be shortened by some not-so-hard greedy algorithms, not sure that it means that $ 10 * d$ are unshortable, but at least not contradict to it. (See https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santa-2023/overview)

Comment: " but there can be longer paths which are still unshortable. "

Do you have a smallish example of this?

Comment: @JoshuaZ trivial example - full graph - so d = 1, any path is "unshortable" 

So for highly connected graphs - it is something similar can get very long paths since "d" is small. 

But the interesting cases  - when "d" is higher. For example even if take the simplest lattice - (Z/n)^d (its Cayley graph) what is the maximal length of the "unshortable" path ?